# PHP Memcached keeps writing to dead server

Tags: php, caching, memcached, distributed

I have this annoying problem I can't seem to wrap my head around. The problem is that my PHP Memcached client keeps attempting to write to a dead server. When I check the stats of the servers, with $memcached->getStats() it looks something like this:

```
{
   "server1:11211": {
      "pid" : 15,
      "uptime" : 600
      ...
   },
   "server2:11211": {
      "pid" : -1,
      "uptime" : 0
      ...
   },
}
```

Which, from my understanding, indicates that server2 is dead? But when I attempt to write data to the cluster it keeps trying to write half of the keys to this dead server. It works great when both server is alive, but as soon as I kill one of them it doesn't seem to affect how the keys are distributed.

My Memcached instance looks like this:

```
protected static function getMemcached()
{
    if(!self::$memcached)
    {
        self::$memcached = new Memcached();

        self::$memcached->setOptions(array(
            Memcached::OPT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT => 100,
            Memcached::OPT_LIBKETAMA_COMPATIBLE => true,
            Memcached::OPT_REMOVE_FAILED_SERVERS => true,
            Memcached::OPT_SERVER_FAILURE_LIMIT => 2,
            Memcached::OPT_RETRY_TIMEOUT => 1
        ));

        // Prevent adding a server to the connection pool each request
        if (!self::$memcached->getServerList())
        {
            // Add new connection
            self::$memcached->addServers(self::getHosts());
        }

    }

    return self::$memcached;
}
```

PHP Info:
[image: PHP Info]

Doesn't `Memcached::OPT_REMOVE_FAILED_SERVERS => true` say that if the server is down, it should be removed from the server pool? Am I not understanding this correctly? When I try to ping the dead server from the PHP client it results in an unknown host error. Do I need to check the status of each server before adding them to the pool with `addServers()`?

Also, every write request has a `getResultMessage()` of SUCCESS.

Really appreciate some input on this,

Answer (score 0):

Check out this Issue on GitHub: https://github.com/php-memcached-dev/php-memcached/issues/154

> What consistent distribution means is that given keys will be stored on given servers no matter what. The distribution will change when you ask driver to recalculate it, by setting distribution method again, which updates hashing function and dead server(s) are no longer used.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If I understand I have to open up a new connection and apply the `Memcached::OPT_LIBKETAMA_COMPATIBLE` option after each get?

Comment: not after each get. I would try something like this:

if (!self::$memcached->getServerList())
{
    // Add new connection
    self::$memcached->addServers(self::getHosts());
}
else 
{
  // get stats and check if a node has failed
  // reconnect to alive servers
}

I haven't tested this solution, but I think the cache will start from scratch because the distribution will change